# Font Awesome 5.0.13 CSS error

Tags: css, unicode, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm using font awesome 5.0.13 latest version but Unicode characters for font awesome not working in my css. Please let me what's the mistake.

```
nav.socials ul li a:before{
   font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 0 5px;
   content: "\f08e";
}
```

Comment: I think you should check the unicode. f08e was external link icon in previous version and now its changed in version 5 as f35d .. Just guessing it.. if not tell us which icon you are trying to get

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: See here:https://fontawesome.com/icons/external-link-alt?style=solid

Comment: @Sandeep Two points to consider 1. The Unicode code is changed in the new version. 2. you need to provide the font-weight:700 for correct rendering. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/1wkj7727/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` you tried **was replaced** in version 5.
 see here:https://fontawesome.com/icons/external-link-alt?style=solid 
And you have to set  `font-weight` in Font Awesome 5 
**SO here is working one:**

```css
a::before{
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
   font-weight: 900;
   content: "\f35d";
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#">try</a>
```

Comment: The library version is different in your answer.

Comment: @Sandeep tell me for more help